# How to use Vuforia Web Services API with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I've trying several things but nothing is really working. There are some examples in Vuforia Web Services API documentation using PHP but there's nothing with JavaScript.

Comment: Hey, can you show us/explain what you've tried? It'll help us help you

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no Javascript API available for `VWS`. Even if it were, you will probably not be able to call it from web browser because of `Cross domain` policies.

That said, you can write your own back-end client in JS or run one of the samples in (Java/PHP/Python) in the server and expose all the methods as `REST` end-points.

`VWS` seems to be plain old `REST` services, which can be called from any language.
Only hurdle in writing your own simple client is to calculate signature for the requests, here's the logic to calculate signature from the documenation

Ref: https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Training/Using-the-VWS-API.html
[image: VWS signature]

After you have the function for signature you will have to convert sample requests from the download for selected language to Javascript

These are the files in sample that I downloaded for Java, (https://github.com/christolb/MobEmbedded/tree/master/Pradeep/VWS%20Sample, it's uploaded by someone else on Github, I'm not adding it here myself, as I'm unsure of the licensing restrictions)

```
DeleteTarget.java
GetAllTargets.java
GetTarget.java
PostNewTarget.java
SignatureBuilder.java
Summary.java
TargetState.java
TargetStatusListener.java
TargetStatusPoller.java
UpdateTarget.java
```